# Read a table from a SAP system using JCo

Tags: java, sapjco3

I am trying to read a table from an SAP system and I am always getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sap.conn.jco.JCoRuntimeException: (127) 
JCO_ERROR_FIELD_NOT_FOUND: Field EMPLOYEE is not a member of INPUT
at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.AbstractMetaData.indexOf(AbstractMetaData.java:404)
at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.AbstractRecord.setValue(AbstractRecord.java:4074)
at testConf.StepServer.main(StepServer.java:50)
```

And here is my code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  // This will create a file called mySAPSystem.jcoDestination
  System.out.println("executing");
  String DESTINATION_NAME1 = "mySAPSystem";

  Properties connectProperties = new Properties();
  connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_ASHOST, "xxx.xxx.x.xxx");
  connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_SYSNR,  "xx");
  connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_CLIENT, "xxx");
  connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_USER,   "username");
  connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_PASSWD, "test");
  connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_LANG,   "en");
  createDestinationDataFile(DESTINATION_NAME1, connectProperties);

  // This will use that destination file to connect to SAP
  try {
      JCoDestination destination = JCoDestinationManager.getDestination("mySAPSystem");
      System.out.println("Attributes:");
      System.out.println(destination.getAttributes());
      System.out.println();
      destination.ping();
  } catch (JCoException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  try{

  //here starts the problem

  JCoDestination destination = JCoDestinationManager.getDestination(DESTINATION_NAME1);
  JCoFunction function = destination.getRepository().getFunction("RFC_READ_TABLE");
  JCoParameterList listParam = function.getImportParameterList();

  listParam.setValue("EMPLOYEE", "EMPLOYEE"); // I have found this in an example and I don't understand exactly what should I put there
                                              // I was thinking maybe is the column name but I am not sure
  function.execute(destination);

  JCoTable table = function.getTableParameterList().getTable("ZEMPLOYEES");//name of my table from SAP

  System.out.println(table);

  }
  catch (JCoException e)
  {
      System.out.println(e.toString());
      return;
  }
 }
```

The error is clear when it says **JCO_ERROR_FIELD_NOT_FOUND: Field EMPLOYEE is not a member of INPUT** but the employee is a field in my table.

[image]

The documentation doesn't help too much, it only says:

```
Sets the object as the value for the named field.
Parameters:
    value - the value to set for the field
    name - the name of the field to set
```

Witch, in my opinion, I have already done.

Should I make any additional modification in sap, in order to read this new table from java? All I have done is to create a new table following this tutorial ([Create a simple table in SAP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2vwjP7QX_NU)).

*Maybe someone with more experience can tell me how should I configure this sample code in order to work.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### General use of RFC_READ_TABLE

I never used JCo, but as far as I know its interface is very similar to NCo, the .Net connector. This is basically NCo code with some guesswork added to it, but it should work.

```
// get the table parameter FIELDS that should be in the parameter list
// the parameter table has several fields, only the field FIELDNAME has to be set before calling the function module
JCOTable inputTableParam = function.getTableParameterList().getTable("FIELDS");

// add a row to the FIELDS table parameter
inputTableParam.appendRow();

// set values for the new row
inputTableParam.setValue("FIELDNAME", "EMPLOYEE");
// just for fun, add another field to retrieve
inputTableParam.appendRow();
inputTableParam.setValue("FIELDNAME", "SURNAME");

// now we have to set the non-table parameters
JCoParameterList inputParamList = function.getImportParameterList();
// parameter QUERY_TABLE, defines which table to query
inputParamList.setValue("QUERY_TABLE", "ZEMPLOYEES");
// parameter DELIMITER - we get a single string as the return value, the field values within that string are delimited by this character
inputParamList.setValue("DELIMITER", ";");

// execute the function
function.execute(destination);

// the parameter table DATA contains the rows
JCoTable table = function.getTableParameterList().getTable("DATA");
```

in the end, your variable `table` will hold a table object with a single field called `WA`. That field contains the contents of the fields you selected in input parameter table `FIELDS`. You can iterate over `table` and get the values row by row.

### Queries with RFC_READ_TABLE

`RFC_READ_TABLE` doesn't really allow queries, it only allows you to define `WHERE` clauses. The `TABLE` parameter `OPTIONS` has a single field `TEXT`, 72 characters wide, that can only take `ABAP` compliant `WHERE` clauses.

to extend the example above, we'll add a where clause to only select entries from table `ZEMPLOYEES` with `SURNAME` = "SMITH" and `FORNAME` = "JOHN".

```
JCOTable optionsTableParam = function.getTableParameterList().getTable("OPTIONS");

// add a row to the FIELDS table parameter
optionsTableParam.appendRow();
optionsTableParam.setValue("TEXT", "SURNAME EQ 'SMITH' AND FORNAME EQ 'JOHN');
```

the field `TEXT` is only 72 characters long, so if you want to add a longer clause, you manually have to break your conditions into several rows. `RFC_READ_TABLE` is a bit crude and limited.

Complex joins between tables can be achieved by creating a view within the SAP system (transaction `SE11`) and then query that view with RFC_READ_TABLE.

If you want to call function modules from JCo, it would be very helpful if you made yourself familiar with the basic function module properties. You can look at a function module definition in transaction `SE37`. There you can see the `IMPORT`, `EXPORT`, `CHANGING` and `TABLE` parameters. The parameters you have to fill and the parameters that contain the results depend on the function module you call - `RFC_READ_TABLE` has different ones from, say, `BAPI_DELIVERY_GETLIST`.

Here is the documentation for JCoFunction and one of the differences between JCo and NCo, JCo has individual functions to get and set the different parameter types: https://help.hana.ondemand.com/javadoc/com/sap/conn/jco/JCoFunction.html

Comment: It fails on this line  JCoTable inputTableParam = listParam.getTable("FIELDS"); with the same error :  JCO_ERROR_FIELD_NOT_FOUND: Field FIELDS is not a member of INPUT.

Comment: yes, looking at the documentation for JcoFunction it seems there is one of the differences between JCo and NCo. I modified my example, you essentially need to call getTableParameterList() for table parameters and getImportParameterList() for input parameters.

Comment: @ Dirk Trilsbeek you are awesome. Can you give me a link to the documentation where you found this? And also is possible to make a query using RFC_READ_TABLE?

Comment: @John I've updated my answer to include the basic query functionality from the function module and the docs for JCoFunction.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I hope you will get the same treatment when you have questions :)

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to call the function RFC_READ_TABLE and you try to pass a value to its parameter named "EMPLOYEE". This is NOT a parameter of RFC_READ_TABLE, hence the error.

RFC_READ_TABLE has 3 important input parameters :

- QUERY_TABLE : the name of the database table you want to query
- OPTIONS : the WHERE clause (you may pass an empty value)
- FIELDS : the list of columns from the database table you want to query

RFC_READ_TABLE has 1 return parameter :

- DATA : the contents of the table

See this example : https://vishalmasih.wordpress.com/2014/10/31/sap-jco-searching-for-a-user-in-the-usr04-table/

Comment: Thank you for your nice explanation. Now things are more clear.

Comment: @Adrian: A "Thank you" in the comments is worth exactly 0 reputation points. I upvoted both: Dirk and Sandra.